# Extending parallel 1 forms to harmonic forms on a compact set

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Based on this question from Peterson's Riemannian Geometry:

> Let $(M,g)$ be an n-dimensional connected Riemannian manifold that is isometric
>   to Euclidean space outside some compact subset $K \subset M$, i.e., $M − K$ is
>   isometric to $\mathbb{R}^n − C$ for some compact set $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. If $\text{Ricg} \geq 0$, show that $M = \mathbb{R}^n$.

There are then two hints, but they basically run into the same problem in opposite directions: the first hint leads you to conclude that there are parallel 1 forms defined on $K$ (after showing $K$ is flat, and thus the whole space is flat), but I cannot go from here to conclude that there are globally defined parallel 1 forms.

The other hint tells you to extend the $n$ parallel 1 forms on $M-K$ to harmonic forms on $M$, and use Bochner's technique to conclude that these extensions are parallel. Again, I see the logic, but I am having trouble seeing how to extend the 1-forms on $M-K$ over $K$.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you tell me which page in the book ?

Comment: Page 230, exercises from chapter 7

Comment: If $K$ is eg a ball with well-behaved boundary, this should follow from a relative form of Hodge theory - you're just solving the Laplace equation on a ball with boundary conditions. Maybe you can then just pick a ball that contains $K$, solve the Laplace equation, and slightly modify your original form so that it extends like so. But I have not thought through the details.

Answer (score 2):

We can assume that $[0,R]^n$ containing $K$ properly That is we have $n$-torus $T$. Since torus haz ${\bf Z}^n$ as first cohomology so there exist $n$ harmonic 1-forms If $X$ is one of them, recall $$ \Delta X_i - R_{ij}X_i =\Delta_d X_i $$

Hence $$\int_T -|\nabla X|^2 =\int_T Rc(X,X)\geq 0 $$

Hence $X$ is parallel. Bundary of $[0,R]^n$ is flat so that we have global parallel $1$-forms on ${\bf R}^n$.

Comment: Yes, my argument basically aligns with yours up to deducing that each $X$ is parallel. I guess my issue is with the conclusion "the boundary is flat, so we have global parallel 1-forms"

Comment: parallel form on flat neighborhood is trivial as we know

Comment: Oh right, so this implies the $X$ have to be constant vector fields, and thus extend globally?

Comment: Yes you are right. ( If $q$ is other point from $p$ and if $c$ is a curve from $p$ to $q$ where $c$ is in flat neighborhood, then we can extend by using parallel transport. )

Comment: I am a bit unsure: you cannot assume $K \subset [0,R]^n$ as $K$ might has topology (Of course you can assume $C \subset [0,R]^n$). Your arugment is fine if you can show that $H^1$ of $[0,R]^n/\sim$ is bigger than or equals to $n$.

Comment: Yes I misunderstand $M={\bf R}^n$. And assume that $C\subset [0,R]^n$ We have set $\partial $ in $M$ which is corresponded to $\partial [0,R]^n$ So by doing quotient we have a compact manifold. It is like a connected sum of torus and some. So as you said, $H^1$ is bigger than or equal to $n$

Comment: @JohnMa I did this with Mayer-Vietoris arguments